# Changing Color of cell in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would really appreciate if someone could help me.

I want to change cell color based on cell value. I can do this with conditional formatting but the orginal file is to big to do it and I am afraid that too many conditional formatting conditions will slow down the spreadsheet...

I created sample spreadsheet to show what I want to achieve.
[Sample SpreadSheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SaGo-yA6YPP-Um68Sgm8H3yMyfqXclDQWl5_l4cxgs4/edit?usp=sharing)
`ConditionalFormating` sheet

There is a list of products and theirs inventory status on the left. Above you have order list and which product it will need. I want to change color of the cell to any color except white to be able to see that I am out of stock for this order.

For example:
`=SUM(D5:F5)>B5` => change color to red

I started to write a code but the I realized that with my approach I would have to write it for every row and then I got stuck...

```
    function myFunction() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ConditionalFormating");
  var range1 = sheet1.getRange(10,7,1,sheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var inv1 = sheet1.getRange(10,3);

  for(var i = 0; i < range1.length; i++){
    if(range1[i] > inv1){
     sheet1.getRange(10,i).setBackground(`red`);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I saw your sample Spreadsheet. But unfortunately, I cannot understand about your goal from your 4 sheets. And I cannot understand about `There is a list of products and theirs inventory status on the left. Above you have order list and which product it will need. I want to change color of the cell to any color except white to be able to see that I am out of stock for this order.`. And I cannot find "COMPONENTS" sheet in your sample Spreadsheet. I apologize for this. where it the sample sheet of your sample input? And, can you provide the sample output situation you expect?

Comment: @Tanaike sample spreadsheet is a sample output. Check the `ConditionalFormating` sheet. Also please check the conditional formatting for each red cell, then I am sure you will understand what my goal is. As you can see there I do not have enough of product A to make orders 2,3,4

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor understanding. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current issue and your goal from the sheet "ConditionalFormating". And also, I cannot understand about `As you can see there I do not have enough of product A to make orders 2,3,4 `. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your sheet "ConditionalFormating", for example, the cell "D4" is the total number from the cells "D5:D7". Cells "D5", "D6" and "D7" are the product "A", "B" and "C", respectively. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, for example, at the row 6, "order 1" and "order 2" are 3 and 1, respectively. In this case, the total orders are 4 and the inventory is 6. By this, the background color is white. And, at 3 of "order 3", the total orders are 7 and this is over the inventory of 6. By this, the background color is red. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, that's correct! But please keep in mind that original data has a lot of more rows and columns

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could confirm that my understanding of your question was correct. As one more question, in the goal of your this question, you want to use the sheet "ConditionalFormating" in your sample Spreadsheet. Is my understanding correct? Because when the sample script is prepared to this situation, when you change the sheet and the structure of sheet is changed, the script cannot be used. I'm worry about this. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike ranges will change because there is over 100 columns and over 300 rows. I put some of the original data into `ConditionalFormating1`sheet so you can see the real ranges and the real structer

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could see the sample "ConditionalFormating1". It was found that this structure is different from 1st one you provided. "ConditionalFormating1" is the same structure of your actual situation? I'm worry about this. Because for example, if the sample script was prepared for your 1st sample sheet, when you tested it for your this "ConditionalFormating1", an error occurs. By the way, in your "ConditionalFormating1", the background color of cells "G11:H14" should be red?

Comment: @Tanaike `ConditionalFormating1` is the correct format and script should work on this sheet. The logic of the script is as we spoke before. Yes, they should be red. I am sorry, I just forgot to color them

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your actual sheet, the cells "B10:C" are "Product" and "Inventory". And, the cells "G10:H" and/or "G10:Z" are the number of orders. Is my understanding correct? I deeply apologize for my too cautious.

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, you are correct. But as I said the whole data has around 150 Columns and around 350 rows

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a sample script as answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize. At that time, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating the issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- In your sheet "ConditionalFormating", for example, the cell "D4" is the total number from the cells "D5:D7". Cells "D5", "D6" and "D7" are the product "A", "B" and "C", respectively.

  - For example, at the row 6, "order 1" and "order 2" are 3 and 1, respectively. In this case, the total orders are 4 and the inventory is 6. By this, the background color is white. And, at 3 of "order 3", the total orders are 7 and this is over the inventory of 6. By this, the background color is red.
- But in your actual situation, the start cells of "Product" and "Inventory" are "B10" and "C10". And, the start cell of "order" is "G10". In your actual situation, you have around 150 Columns and around 350 rows.

In this case, I would like to propose the following sample script.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of your sample Spreadsheet. And, please set the sheet name, and run the script. By this, the background colors of cells starting from "G10" are modified. When your sample "ConditionalFormating1" sheet is used, "G10" is white and the cells "H10" and "G11:H14" are red.

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "###";  // Please set the sheet name.

  // 1. Retrieve values from sheet.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const values = sheet.getRange(10, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 9, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  
  // 2. Create an array for modifying the background colors.
  const backgroundColors = values.map(([,,c,,,,...g]) =>
    g.reduce((o, e) => {
      if (e.toString() != "") {
        o.total += e;
        o.colors.push(c >= o.total ? null : "red");
      } else {
        o.colors.push(null);
      }
      return o;
    }, {colors: [], total: 0}).colors
  );
  
  // 3. Modify the background colors of cells.
  sheet.getRange(10, 7, backgroundColors.length, backgroundColors[0].length).setBackgrounds(backgroundColors);
}
```

#### Note:

- This sample script is for the sheet of ConditionalFormating1 in your 2nd sample Spreadsheet. So when the structure of sheet is changed, the script is required to be modified. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [setBackgrounds(color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundscolor)

Comment: it almost works. It is getting wrong in few rows, I put it into the sheet ConditionalFormatting1

Comment: @Timonek Thank you for replying. I saw your updated sample Spreadsheet. The reason of your current issue is due to that I couldn't know that you use the empty cells from your sample sheets. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. I updated my proposed sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Sorry for that! I should explain that there are empty cells as well. Now it is working perfect! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Timonek Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.